# Why is 0 appearing in my code while working with text files

Tags: c++, file, text, int, output

I have a text file with inside made of:

```
3
7 8 9 7 8
5 7 9 5 7
6 8 7 9 7
```

I have set 3 to int 'd'. All other lines should belong to int 'b'. But it seems that 'b' still counts in the first line, which became 0 after extracting it to 'd'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b, d;
    string line;
    ifstream file("File.txt");

    if(!file.is_open())
        cout << "File failed to open." << endl;

    file >> d;

    while(getline(file, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        double v = 0;

        while(iss >> b)
            v += b;

        cout << v / 5 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
0
7.8
6.6
7.4
```

What could I do to fix this ? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `std::getline` after you've read with `operator>>`, which doesn't consume whitespace characters (including newline) after the extraction is done.

So, the newline character is still there, your first `std::getline` reads till that character (in your case nothing - `iss` is empty) and extraction `iss >> b` fails, thus `v` is not incremented. Do

```
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

after `file >> d;` to consume the newline character and continue reading on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
file >> d;
```

the newline character is still in the input stream. The first call to `getline` returns an empty line.

Use

```
file >> d;

// Ignore the rest of the first line.
file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

while(getline(file,line))
```

And make sure to add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std:numeric_limits`.

Comment: #include<limits> for numeric_limits